# string decode method error in python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a function like this:

```
def convert_to_unicode(data):
    row = {}
    if data == None:
        return data
    try:
        for key, val in data.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                row[key] = unicode(val.decode('utf8'))
            else:
                row[key] = val
        return row
    except Exception, ex:
        log.debug(ex)
```

to which I feed a result set (got using `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`) row by row to transform all the string values to unicode (example `{'column_1':'XXX'}` becomes `{'column_1':u'XXX'}`).

Problem is one of the rows has a value like `{'column_1':'Gabriel García Márquez'}`
and it does not get transformed. it throws this error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

When I searched for this it seems that this has to do with ascii encoding.

The solutions i tried are:

1. adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of my file ... does not help
2. changing the line `row[key] = unicode(val.decode('utf8'))` to `row[key] = unicode(val.decode('utf8', 'ignore'))` ... as expected it ignores the non-ascii character and returns `{'column_1':u'Gabriel Garca Mrquez'}`
3. changing the line `row[key] = unicode(val.decode('utf8'))` to `row[key] = unicode(val.decode('latin-1'))` ... Does the job but I am afraid it will support only West Europe characters (as per [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) )

Can anybody point me towards a right direction please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly:

- The data you're getting in your result set is clearly `latin-1` encoded, or you wouldn't be observing this behavior. It is *entirely correct* that trying to decode a `latin-1`-encoded byte string as though it were `utf-8`-encoded blows up in your face. Once you have a `latin-1`-encoded byte string `foo`, if you want to convert it to the unicode type, `foo.decode('latin1')` is the right thing to do.
- I noticed the expression `unicode(val.decode('utf8'))` in your code. This is equivalent to just `val.decode('utf8')`; calling the `.decode` method of a byte string converts it to unicode, so you're calling `unicode()` on a unicode string, which just returns the unicode string.

Secondly:

- Your real problem here - if you want to be able to deal with characters not included in the character set supported by the `latin-1` encoding - is not with Python's string types, per se, so much as it is with the MySQLdb library. I don't know this problem in intimate detail, but as I understand it, in ancient versions of MySQL, the default encoding used by MySQL databases was `latin-1`, but now it is `utf-8` (and has been for many years). The MySQLdb library, however, still by default establishes `latin-1`-encoded connections with the database. There are literally dozens of StackOverflow questions relating to MySQL, Python, and string encoding, and while I don't fully understand them, one easy-to-use solution to all such problems that seems to work for people is this one:
  http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2007/12/17/python-mysqldb-and-utf-8

I wish I could give you a more comprehensive and confident answer on the MySQLdb issue, but I've never even used MySQL and I don't want to risk posting anything untrue. Perhaps someone can come along and provide more detail. Nonetheless, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Your third solution - changing the encoding to `"latin-1"` - is correct. Your input data is encoded as Latin-1, so that's what you have to decode it as. Unless someone somewhere did something very silly, it should be impossible for that input data to contain invalid characters for that encoding.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help :)